# How to make in-place changes to a tensor local to a method in a method it is not local to, in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pass-by-reference, tensor

We know that in python, data is passed by name across methods. Say I have a list **a**, which is local to a method m1() and I wanted to pass it up to another method and do some changes to it in some other method and retain these changes, then it is pretty straight-forward and can be done as follows:

```
def m1(a):
   a.append(5)
def m2():
   a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
   print('Before: ', a) # Output= Before: [1, 2, 3, 4]
   m1(a)
   print('After: ', a) # Output= After: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
m2()
```

How to do the same if **a** was a tensor? I want to do something like

```
def m1(t1):
  t2 = tf.constant([[[7, 4], [8, 4]], [[2, 10], [15, 11]]])
  tf.concat([t1, t2], axis = -1)


def m2():
  t1 = tf.constant([[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 4], [5, 3]]])
  se = tf.Session()
  print('Before: ', se.run(t1)) # Output = Before: [[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 4], [5, 3]]]
  m1(t1)
  print('After: ', se.run(t1))  #Actual Output = After : [[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 4], [5, 3]]] | Desired Output = After : [[[1, 2, 7, 4], [2, 3, 8, 4]], [[4, 4, 2, 10], [5, 3, 15, 11]]]

m2()
```

Comment: Use return values to pass things out of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.concat` actually returns the concatenated tensor and does not do it in place, as tensorflow basically works on adding new nodes in the graph. So, this new tensor is added to the graph.

This code works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def m1(t1):
  t2 = tf.constant([[[7, 4], [8, 4]], [[2, 10], [15, 11]]])
  return tf.concat([t1, t2], axis = -1)

def m2():
  t1 = tf.constant([[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 4], [5, 3]]])
  se = tf.Session()
  print('Before: ', se.run(t1)) # Output = Before: [[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 4], [5, 3]]]
  t1 = m1(t1)
  print('After: ', se.run(t1))  #Actual Output = After : [[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 4], [5, 3]]] | Desired Output = After : [[[1, 2, 7, 4], [2, 3, 8, 4]], [[4, 4, 2, 10], [5, 3, 15, 11]]]

m2()
```

It gives the following output:

```
('Before: ', array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 3]]], dtype=int32))
('After: ', array([[[ 1,  2,  7,  4],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  4]],

       [[ 4,  4,  2, 10],
        [ 5,  3, 15, 11]]], dtype=int32))
```

Refer this [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat)